Show that $\{\sum_{i=N}^{\infty} a_i x^i\}$ forms a Field where $N$ is an Arbitrary Integer and $a_i \in \mathbb{Z}/p\mathbb{Z}$
I am trying to construct an infinite field with finite characteristic. This ring of polynomials $T=\{\sum_{i=N}^{\infty} a_i x^i: a_i \in \mathbb{Z}/p\mathbb{Z}, N\in \mathbb{Z}\}$ where $N$ is possibly negative should do as long as we show that all nonzero elements in $T$ are invertible. How should I go about proving that?

What have you done so far?

Cf. this question

Hint: It is still true if you replace $\mathbb Z/p\mathbb Z$ with any field $F.$

This is the ring of formal Laurent series, not polynomials. An easier construction is to take the rational functions $\mathbb{F}_p(x)$.
